# How to recover content from a variable when the activity changes state?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two activities

- MainActivity
- NormalStudentActivity

Since the **MainActivity** shares a data towards the other activity **NormalStudentActivity**

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val intent = Intent(this, NormalStudentActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("tipo", "normal")
startActivity(intent)
```

Now within NormalStudentActivity I create a general variable
`lateinit var temario:String`

```
class NormalStudentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  lateinit var temario:String

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_student)

        val data = intent.extras
        tem = data.get("tipo").toString()

        if (tem !=null){
            temario = tem
             // add data to spinner ------------>
             //======================================
            val spnnormal = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.DistNormal,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
                spnnormal.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            spnnTipo.adapter = spnnormal
            //=====================================
        }
  }

      override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState?.putString("temas",tem)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        val str = savedInstanceState?.getString("temas")
        temario = str.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, "variable restored --> $temario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
}
```

But it generates an error and that is when I rotate the screen of the device I get an error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mrl.fred.alumn, PID: 31186
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter view
        at com.mrl.fred.alumn.NormalStudentActivity$onCreate$1.onItemSelected(NormalStudentActivity.kt)
```

---

The problem is that the variable **temario**, generates a **null value** and I use this same to condition in other events as in a **spinner onItemSelected**

---

```
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                when(position){
                    1 ->{
                        //hight
                        textView34.text = "Long"
                        txtUnico.text = ""
                        if (temario == "student"){
                            editText2.hint = "Insert Weight"
                        }
                    }
                    2 ->{
                        // number student
                        textView34.text = ""
                        txtUnico.text = ""
                        if (temario == "student"){
                            editText2.hint = "Insert number"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

> Action in Spinner

---

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_student)

        spnnTipo.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                when(position){
                    1 ->{
                        //data
                        textView34.text = "Density weight"
                        txtUnico.text = ""
                        if (temario == "student"){
                            editText2.hint = "Insert data"
                        }
                    }
                    2 ->{
                        // Student angry
                        textView34.text = ""
                        txtUnico.text = ""
                        if (temario == "student"){
                            editText2.hint = "Insert value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're not including the code that is actually causing the issue. The crash indicates an error in an onItemSelected() callback method.

Comment: Yes, of course, it is that I use the variable **temario** to condition certain data and show the related content

Comment: Where are you setting the item selected listener? From the exception it appears that the `view` parameter is null.

Comment: inside of the `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){ //here}` of **NormalStudentActivity**

Comment: The error is that the `view` parameter on the `onItemSelected(..)` shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: Could you please explain? Excuse me, I do not understand the situation so much.

Comment: Can you please post your Spinner's selection listener? And also the code where you are creating and assigning the listener.

Comment: I have added data that are very important in the error, excuse my ignorance, now if